# Casting memory location to get String

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to access a variable from a Win32 app which have a known variable based on the source code:

```
Foo foo; // Class foo
foo.mystring = "All your base are belong to us"; // where this is defined as: 'string mystring'
```

Now the I tried to disassemble the PE using a disassembler and I got found this

```
.rdata:00446074 aAllYourBaseAre db 'all your base are belong to us',0
```

Now I have another win32 process that gets the image base address of the former win32 app which have the class variable I need.

I get the process address with this code:

```
HMODULE parent = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if (parent) {
   const BYTE* imageBase = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> ( parent );
   const char* strMemberValue = *reinterpret_cast<const char**>((unsigned char*)imageBase + 0x00446074); 
            std::cout << "Value=" << strMemberValue;
}
```

The parent is the process that I am trying to gain access to. I also have tested that the parent is the right process. The problem is that when I try to get the string by casting the base address + offset I can't get anything.

**EDIT:**

I missed my point. There is no way I can recompile the target Win32 app, its already in production. However I need to access some variables on that executable. The code I have here is merely a Proof-of-concept**

Also I am doing "DLL injection"

DEBUG:

Since a class is a struct with methods, I am assuming this code I dig using IDAPro is the class definition of `Foo`

```
00000000 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
00000000
00000000 ; (Class Informer)
00000000 type_info       struc ; (sizeof=0x8, variable size)
00000000 vftable         dd ?                    ; offset (00000000)
00000004 _m_data         dd ?
00000008 _m_d_name       db 0 dup(?)             ; string(C)
00000008 type_info       ends
00000008
00000000 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However I am still uncertain about this.

Comment: Oh god what are you doing stop

Comment: I'm looking into doing this in a sane way.  Basically, you're trying to do things that linkers do.  You can use dynamic linking from C++; you might want to look up how to make a DLL call.

Comment: This is because the you will need to *load* the dll to get the exact address (which would typically be a high address + the address specified in the object file). As-is, the address is unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the process memory in the wrong way through a **double** indirection. `.rdata:00446074` is the address where the string is located, not a pointer to the actual location. You should access it like:

```
HMODULE parent = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if (parent) {
   const BYTE* imageBase = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> ( parent );
   const char* strMemberValue = (const char *)imageBase + 0x00446074; 
   std::cout << "Value=" << strMemberValue;
}
```

Besides, are you sure that the disassembler bases the image at `0x0` and not at the default PE base address of `0x00400000`, in which case the RVA of the string would be `0x00046074` and not `0x00446074`. Also this is the string constant that is used to initialise the member variable, not the variable itself.

Comment: You're right, i'm getting the right offset, when I tried this code, I can't any string value. Do you have any idea on how to get variable offset?

Comment: Run the program with a debugger and see if the string is at the expected address. Heap and automatic variables are hard to impossible to locate at runtime. Static variables on the other hand have their storage location fixed and can be found via the (debug) symbol table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,first thing to note: When deailing with foreign process memories you wont probably find any data anymore if you recompile your other executable. The linker is free to place data and code anywhere and rearrange it. To refind certain values or functions you'll have to search for a binary pattern.

Next thing to note: Your actually having a member variable. That means that it contents can actually be different for every object. Your currently searching for the string which is default assigned to it (and not to the member directly but somewhere in the std::string class).

Ad last but not least: When you try to access the contents of a foreign process you'll have to use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Consider using Shared Memory for inter process communication though. Named pipes would also do.

The most easiest way to access the real value is to pass the address of  your `Foo` object e.g `&foo` to your reading process and put the `Foo` class in a common project base accessable by both projects.
Then read the whole object into your address space (see `ReadProcessMemory` above) and access the member as you would access any other member. Please notice though that your actually dealing with a copy of the real object. Shared Memory can make a single object accessable to both processes ([CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: OK I missed my point. There is no way I can recompile the target Win32 app, its already in production. However I need to access some variables on that executable. The code I have here is merely a Proof-of-concept

Comment: Yes in this case your actually reverse engineering. The methods described above applies though. Copy memory with `ReadProcessMemory` if your creating a external application (DLL Injection can overcome this, you can then directly access the contents of the foreign address space) and use binary patterns to find certain pieces of code again. Also notice that you can define a class which has the same layout as the foreign class and cast to it. Use `char[]` to skip unkwon contents.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, to cast the memory location into the class I need. However its very hard to get the offset to which to cast. BTW, my case is "DLL injections", that is, the application I need to access memory to actually loads the DLL

Comment: I wrote the answere multiple times: 1. Create a POD struct if its a real structure or a class if its a polymorphic class (in this case you'll have to define your class polymorphic too). 2. Obtain a pointer to the memory location where the object is located 3. Simply do a static cast if you have a void* or a reinterprete_cast if you have a char* and use the pointer as you would use any other pointer. I really dont get your problem... This works 100%, but we cant write the whole program for you...